# Should I set lastError to null manually?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this helper method on Angular6 class:

```
  saveToLocalStorage(key: string, val: any): Promise<void | LastErrorType> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      chrome.storage.local.set({ [key]: val }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Looking at this code again after a few months it has me wondering, should I manually set the error to null here:

```
   chrome.storage.local.set({ [key]: val }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          chrome.runtime.lastError = null;  // <<< necessary?
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
```

Or does chrome.runtime handle this somehow? Obvious, later in the program if chrome.runtime.lastError is still defined, I would be seeing an error that may no longer be relevant? Anyone know what I am talking about?

Comment: Checking lastError is needed to prevent console messages in case of errors. You don't need to clear it manually. Each API call sets it anew.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to do it.

[According to the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError), `chrome.runtime.lastError` will only be set for the callback chain of the specific event that raised the error.

Once you're handling another event, it will be reset.